# Create a linked database in SQL Server as a local database

Tags: sql-server, database, proxy, linked-server

I would like to make a linked server like it is part of the main server (like the secondary/linked server does not exist).

I have two database servers A & B. I can create a linked server in A to B, as I can't reach B directly.

But to access or execute request I have to specify the name of the linked server :

```
select * 
from [B].database.dbo.table
```

I would like to be able to write statements like if the database on  server B is on the server A

```
select * 
from database.dbo.table
```

I managed to link the server but cannot make a linked database as part of the principal server.

Servers are not in the same version.

Comment: No, there is no "linked database" feature. If you wanted the database on both servers, you might want to look at mirroring or similar.

Comment: Mirroring seems to be  available only between server with the same version. In my case it is not.

Comment: This is why I stated "or similar". That the 2 servers are running different versions of SQL Server isn't in your question.

Comment: you are right, i added it

Comment: None of this changes my answer, mind; there is no "linked database" feature. An "alternative" you could do would be to create a database on your first server, and then create `SYNONYM`s for (certain) objects on your linked server; then you could reference those `SYNONYM`s. note that this wouldn't be created "automagically"; you would need to create (and update) *any and **all*** the `SYNONYM`s you need.

Comment: Thanks but it won't suit me. I have to many objects.

Comment: You can create a db on server A which contains a bunch of views that are automatically scripted from server B and that point to it through the linked server. It ain't pretty though

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.